# Подключение flash-объекта в модуле джумлы

Tags: joomla, flash

К странице через модуль подключается flash-объект

```
<div class="teaser">
    <object width="400" height="240" data="flash/animate_logo.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
    <param name="quality" value="high">
    <param name="src" value="flash/animate_logo.swf">
    <embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="400" height="240" src="flash/animate_logo.swf" />
    </object>
</div>
```

для хранения animate_logo.swf создана папка \templates\test2\flash
Но на странице флэш не отображается, в консоли ошибка
GET http://test2/flash/animate_logo.swf 404 (Not Found) 
В чем причина?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не силён в Joomla'e, но Ваша ошибка означает, что всё таки не такой путь до флэшки. Попробуйте посмотреть пути, например, картинок на сайте, которые точно открываются и по аналогии прописать путь. Попробуйте закинуть в корень сайта, использовать относительные пути через /flash/animate_logo.swf.

Comment: Да, точно, путь неправильный.  
Пробую прописать путь так http://jsfiddle.net/e3NKr/ , но выдается ошибка Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?' in D:\Disk_d\Server\domains\test2\www\modules\mod_header\mod_header.php on line 5
То есть, я неправильно пишу пхп, но не могу разобраться, как надо правильно.

Comment: Не силён в пхп, можем быть там проблема с ковычками при вставке пхп-вставок?